# Problems generating .cs files from .proto in VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I'm trying to edit an existing .proto file in VS2010 to add a new property to it. When I get the Visual Studio tool to regenerate the class, it deletes the file instead.

Anyone seen this problem before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing to check; is the "custom tool" still set against the .proto file in the properties window ( <kbd>f4</kbd> )

If it has deleted the file, I would *expect* that means the .proto is being problematic (in particular, it is very sensitive to encoding - it requires BOM-less UTF8 if I recall - a "feature" of the standard "protoc" that is used to parse the .proto into a tree).

If this *is* the case, I would expec there to be a build warning (which also tells you how to fix it, although rather annoyingly I think the UI is slightly different in VS2010 than VS2008).

I could also be entirely wrong; if so, please say so that I can investigate further.

Also: are you editing the .proto or the .cs? Avoid editing the .cs - if you want to add members, use "partial classes" instead.

Comment: Bingo, it was the encoding. Thanks!